# Rotation Matrix from l1 to l_infinity

Tags: linear-algebra

Both the ell_1 unit ball and ell_infinity unit ball are cubes.
What scaling factor and rotation matrix that will map one of these cubes to the other?

Comment: Notice that this is only possible in two dimensions. Already in three dimensions the L1 ball has six corners while the l_infty ball has 8.

Comment: Thanks. Does it make sense to ask if there is a (non-bijection) function from L1 to L_infty?

Comment: You can embed $\ell_1$ into $\ell_\infty$. A cute way to do this is using exponentially distributed random variables. See also https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/ba-a4.pdf for more stuff like this.